# Taking in input for a 2d Array with 10 rows and three columns

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, user-input

I want the array to take in three arguments and fill the 10x3 array with user input, Once this happens I want it to be able to take in arguments that look at the third column to determine if a space is available from `array[0,2]` to `array[4,2]` and if not I want the spaces from `array[5,2]` to `array[9,2]` to be checked to see if available but only for small dogs. Now the other small things like confirming or not available are small if statements within these portions, and displaying will be making a call back to the method once everything has been executed. So I am assuming my method will need a return to keep all the values that the user has put in for the array. My problem is figuring the syntax for this. My current method for array takes in values but will not display properly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PetKennel
{   

 class Program
  {
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    /*Consider the following scenario:  
    A doggy daycare service has hired you to create a new reservation 
    system.
    Use a 2 dimensional array to note which kennels are reserved for the 
    day.
    Assume that you only reserve one day at a time.
   •    There are two types of kennels: large dog and small dog.
   •    There are a 5 kennels of each type; one row of the array 
    represents each kennel type(i.e., first row is small dog, 2nd row is 
    large dog. )
   •    If all small dog kennels are reserved, but a large dog kennel is 
     open, a large dog kennel can be reserved for a small dog.
     Application Design requirements:
    Create a C# application that prompts the user for the reservation 
    type, verifies availability and reserves a kennel.
    For each reservation attempt, 
    you should display a message telling the user that the reservation 
    was “confirmed” or is “Not available” 
    and print out the entire reservation schedule for that day as shown 
    in the example below.
    You should also have a display option so that the reservation list 
    may be viewed prior to selection of a room.
    The reservation should be handled by a class that uses a 2 dimension 
    array.  (For example (only):       Array[kennel typ][kennel number]  
    ).*/




//initialize array
        int[,] array = new int[10,3];
        //displays array
        OutputArray(array);
    }
       //method to create array
    static void OutputArray(int[,] array)
    {
          //Header
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Size", 2}{"   Room", 2}");
          //loops array row
        for(var row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); ++row)
        {
               //loops through each column
            for (var col = 0; col < array.GetLength(1); ++col)
            {
                //user asked for input
                Console.WriteLine("Enter size of dog, 1 for small or 2 for 
      large.");
                array[row, col] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            //space in between each row
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        //Keep console open
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to be able to take in arguments that look at the third column to determine if a space is available from array[0,2] to array[4,2] and if not i want the spaces from array[5,2] to array[9,2] 
>   *My problem is figuring the syntax for this.*

Add another method that iterates through column 2 checking if its available (and you can add logic for small or large dogs):

```
static int NextSpaceAvailable(int[,] array) 
{
 for (var row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); ++row)
 {      
   if (array[row, 2] = 0)
   {
       //This space is available
       return row;
   }
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Comment: With the above code, is the for loop going through the row, and then executing the bool if statement? and if so then is the condition saying look at each row and at column 2, and if it is zero then true, and ill put would you like to reserve, and if so change it to a 1, else if not 0 then say not available correct?